# CSS: full window pop-up box

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm working with a wordpress theme. I don't know PHP so can't edit the files, and unable to add bootstrap with it. But I need a pop-up box in my page, so I used CSS. But the problem is the pop-up window poping up within the parent window, I want it full screen. How can i do it? Check Screenshot and code here: http://justpaste.it/n4ol

Comment: Please include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself

Comment: You should include all code as part of the question itself; not as links. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: I was tried to add code here, but got some error. That's why I post it different place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use new popup?

Here is the

```
        <html>
<head>
    <title>LIGHTBOX EXAMPLE</title>
    <style>
    .black_overlay{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        opacity:.80;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }
    .white_content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 16px solid orange;
        background-color: white;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the main content. To display a lightbox click <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here</a></p>
    <div id="light" class="white_content">This is the lightbox content. <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>
```

Try this

Use this popup in footer. You will find help .

Comment: Whao! Best one.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
.popup{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   left:0;
   bottom:0;
}
```